# MySQL Table for Items

Tags: mysql, database

I have to create a database to store items like:

IMAGES

TEXTS

MAGAZINE

NEWSPAPERS

MULTIMEDIA

Each item have a common fields like, Title, Date, Author but items have a specific field too, like Duration for Multimedia, Edition for magazine and Photographer for Images.

First idea is to create a table for each item, but user ask to select item type, after record insertion.

I'm like to create a single table, like wordpress (pages and posts are on same table if I remember right) and for this case ITEMS table have structure like below:

item_id

item_classification_id

item_title

item_date

item_author

item_duration

item_edition

item_photographer

... many, many others fileds

for exemple, if select a photo, item_duration and item_edition is empty and item_photographer is filled up, same for image, photographer is filled up and edition and duration are empty.

Any advice to proceed in this way? Table should store few million items...

Thanks all for helping!!
...

Comment: And what is the question? Do this.

Comment: In database it is best to keep your database scheme Simple 
 you can make different table for each

Comment: Btw. I suggest to don't add `item_` prefix to each field. I used to do it too and now it is quite uncomfortable now.

Comment: Thanks for answers, My idea is to add item_ (TYPE) _field to make database more understandable